# How to handle multivariate data with varying time lengths in an LSTM?

Tags: time-series, lstm, varying

The dataset I have is a medical dataset, where measurements were taken at 6 month intervals. Now I want the model to predict 5 years into the future. However there are a lot of subjects that only have for example the first three years of 6 month interval data. How do I still use this data to build a LSTM where the objective is to forecast a value 5 years into the future? Do I have to do something with padding and masking?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @BillyG. Please review the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, you will need to use 0 padding so that all sequences have the same length.